# Rephrasing statements in terms of Eigenfunctions, Eigenvalues and Eigenspaces of Differential Operator

Tags: derivatives, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, intuition, eigenfunctions

Let $V$ be a set of functions that are infinitely differentiable, real, $2\pi$-periodic functions. Also, let $D = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ be the second derivative function that is a linear transformation.

What does it mean for the following in terms of eigenvalues, eigenfunctions, and eigenspaces of D:

- Let $\lambda \in  \mathbb{R}$. If  $f \in  V$ satisfies $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \, f''(x) = \lambda f(x)$ then $\lambda  = \lambda_n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$.
- Let $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$. If $f \in V$ satisfies $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \, f''(x) = \lambda_n f(x)$  then there exists unique $A,B \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \, f(x) = A \sin(n x) + B \cos(n x)$.
- If $f  \in V$ satisfies $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f''(x)  =  0$ then $f$ is constant.

I need a conceptual breakdown of what these really mean. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to check that $D$ is a linear map from $V$ to $V$. The first statement claims that the set of eigenvalues of $D$ is countable. The second means for each eigenvalue $\lambda_n=-n^2>0$ the linear space of the eigenvectors with  eigenvalues is two-dimensional with a basis $\{\sin nx,\cos nx\}$. The third statement means that the linear space of the eigenvectors with  eigenvalue $0$ is an one-dimensional space of constant functions.

Comment: For the first statement, how did you find that conclusion?

Comment: @LetmeKnow It is more like a translation form one language to another than a conclusion. A condition $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \, f''(x) = \lambda f(x)$ means $f$ is an eigenvector of $D$ corresponding to some eigenvalue $\lambda$ and a condition $\lambda  = \lambda_n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$ means that there are only countable many choices for $\lambda$.

Comment: For second point, I thought $\lambda_n = -n^2$ because $D \sin x = -n^2 \sin x$. Why have you found that it's positive?

Comment: @LetmeKnow Oops, your are right. Sorry. Fixed.

Comment: if we add the condition that $\lambda$ must be non-zero, how does this affect our rephrasing?

Comment: @LetmeKnow Then we skip the third statement.